# Jquery input auto clear text

Tags: jquery, html

I need to clear text and hide image when someone delete the message inside an input text using jquery here is my code but is not working now someone show me sample in snippet?

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var urltext = $("#https_urllink").val();
    $("#https_urllink").onkeydow(function(){
    if(urltext == ""){
    $("#httpstext").text("");
    $("#httpsimage").hide();
   }else if(urltext != "www.ilik.com"){
$("#httpstext").text("hello no");
} }); });
    </script>
```

**Here is my HTML**

```
<img src="hmm.png" id="httpsimage"/>
<div id="httpstext">See her</div> 
<input type="text" id="https_urllink" value="delete now"/>
```

Comment: onkeydow(function(){ ??  should be onkeydown(function(){

Comment: also try checking the empty value like if(urltext.length < 1)

Comment: It didn't work @Poria

Comment: @Poria in jquery events, we never use `on` for key event triggers. just `keydown`, `keyup`, `keypress`, `click` thats all.

Comment: @KirsSudh Sorry my bad.. yes you are absolutely right !

Answer (score 0):

I found two problems in this code.

Firstly, the event `keydown` was mis-spelt as `$("#https_urllink").onkeydow(function(){` and also `on` has been included, which is not required.

Secondly, when ever you are using the `input type="text"`, jquery will update the field as if a user did. So, instead of using `$("#httpstext").text("");` we can use `$("#httpstext").val("");` .

below code might solve your issue.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
urltext = $("#https_urllink").val();
$("#https_urllink").keydown(function(){
if(urltext == ""){
$("#httpstext").val("");
$("#httpsimage").hide();
       }
  });
});
</script>
```

Updated

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#https_urllink").keydown(function() {
    if ($("#https_urllink").val() == "") {
      $("#httpstext").val('');
       $("#httpsimage").hide();
      return false;
    } else if($("#httpstext").val() != "www.ilik.com") {
      $("#httpstext").val('hello no');
       $("#httpsimage").hide();
      return true;
    }
  });
});
```

Above code is working now. You can check the fiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/b0p14sfa/1/

Comment: It didn't work here, and i edited my question concerning urltext @Kirs

Comment: Another important confirmation that you are checking the field value right? So, the  code below ` if(urltext == ""){` will be executed only if `$("#https_urllink")` value is empty. The fields, is already empty and your are clearing the value of the empty field. It does not make sense to put a check over there. Please reconsider your requirement.

Comment: It suppose to be `if(urltext != ""){`. Please try this.

Comment: instead of  using `}else if(urltext != "www.ilik.com"){
$("#httpstext").text("hello no");
} }); });`, you can use `}else if(urltext != "www.ilik.com"){
$("#httpstext").val("hello no");
} }); });`

Answer (score 0):

Fix the following and it will work.

1. Use `$("#https_urllink").on('keydown', function(){}`
2. Check the value of `$("#https_urllink").val();` inside the `keydown` event handler as the value may have changed. Calling it in `$(document).ready()` will not reflect the changes.
3. Use `$("#httpstext").html();` instead of `$("#httpstext").val();`. divs don't have value so calling `.val()` will not work.

Look at the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#https_urllink").on('keydown', function(){
        urltext = $("#https_urllink").val();
        if(urltext == ""){
            $("#httpstext").html("");
            $("#httpsimage").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code urltext is always 'delete now'. because you are taking the value only at document ready. You need to get the value on keydown event.then it will work.

Also i suggest you to use keyup instead of keydown.

I have updated the code. please have try, hope it will help you

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#https_urllink").keyup(function(){
        var urltext = $("#https_urllink").val();
    console.log(urltext);       
    if(urltext == ""){
        $("#httpstext").text("");
        $("#httpsimage").hide();
        return false;
    }
    else if(urltext != "www.ilik.com"){
        $("#httpstext").text("hello no");
         $("#httpsimage").show();
        return true;

    }
 }); });
</script>

<img src="hmm.png" id="httpsimage" height="150" width="100"/>
<div id="httpstext">See her</div> 
<input type="text" id="https_urllink" value="delete now"/>**strong text**
```